# I can't seem to set default value for multidimensional array in c++

Tags: multidimensional-array, sdl, default-value

I am trying to set default values for a bool 2d array called "display[Width][Height]" to false. I am getting the error "IntelliSense: braces cannot be omitted for this subobject initializer". The problem is I used this code before and it worked but not anymore. I have these two implementation and header files:

Matrix.cpp (i have indicated where i get the error)

```
#include "Matrix.h"

Matrix::Matrix():
display{ false }     // error is in this line
{

}
```

Matrix.h

```
#pragma once
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL_ttf.h"
#include <iostream>

class Matrix{
public:
    Matrix();
    enum { Width = 10, Height = 20 };
private:
    bool display[Width][Height];

};
```

Comment: It works fine with gcc and clang.

Comment: Have you tried empty braces ? i.e. display{} ?

Comment: I tried display{} and it worked! thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

The code works on Linux gcc but not on visual studio. The proper way is to emit the false within the brackets; so display{}